Do compactifications in string theory actually need to be compact?
I recently saw a talk about string theory and the goal of compactifications seemed to be to reduce the influence of dimensions that we currently don't observe. Is there a particular reason why these dimensions need to be truly compact and hence closed? Or is only boundedness what really matters here and are compact sets chosen for mathematical convenience down the road? I'm not a physicist but am hoping that there's an explanation that someone familiar with real analysis and the basics of manifolds could follow.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Making a dimension compact by adding a point at infinity changes its topology from a line to a circle. If the radius of this circle is very short, you come back to the start before you have traveled a noticeable distance along it. Are you asking if you could achieve the same thing simply by making the dimension a short line segment? Perhaps an open short line segment?

Essentially, yes. The real line is homeomorphic to any short open interval or for example a circle from which a single point is missing and I was wondering if such sets or similar ones would be suitable as well or if they have to be compact.

I was thinking that if we'd map the dimension to a small interval, values would get closer together but never actually reach the "end of space". If this is undesirable and values looping back like in a circle is a requirement, I guess that would answer my question. Edit: I replied to a comment that was deleted asking me what would happen if particles etc reach the "end of space".

I haven't studied string theory very much but what mmesser says is true. I'd imagine that a line segment topology would lead to finite compactified dimensions (i.e. curves terminate after traveling a finite distance), which doesn't make much physical sense. If that were the case I'd ask "what happens when a particle tries to cross over the edge of the compactified dimension once at an energy where it is no longer compact?" / vs. a closed extra dimension that doesn't have such limitations.

Really what matters first of all is not the topological nature of the extra spatial dimensions as being compact, but their Riemannian nature of having finite volume - because when the dimensions have finite volume, you can make that finite volume so small you can argue that we haven't seen those extra dimensions so far because they're small. Since compact Riemannian manifolds have finite volume, they are natural candidates to examine in this context.
Secondly, the purpose of compactification is not only to hide the extra dimensions, but also to generate the correct particle content for the reality we observe by strings and branes "wrapping around" the extra dimensions. This "wrapping around" is in mathematical terms about the non-trivial homology cycles of the manifold of extra dimensions, and the (co)homology theory of compact manifolds is comparatively nice (e.g. because we have Poincaré duality), so they'd be popular among string phenomenologists for that reason, too.
Thirdly, "Finite volumification" does not have quite the same ring to it, I guess.

String theory has nine spatial dimensions, but the visible world has three spatial dimensions.  If the other six dimensions are also large, what keeps the visible matter of the world from drifting away into those six other directions? This is the usual argument for compactification - if the extra dimensions are compact and very small, there simply isn't room for that to happen.
However, there is another way - a "braneworld". Strings can be attached to branes, and if the visible world is made of strings attached to a 3-brane (or to a 3-dimensional overlap of branes), they won't drift into the extra dimensions, even if those dimensions are large.
